# cmake doesn't link libGLU using QtOpenGL

Tags: opengl, qt4, cmake, glu

I'm trying to compile a software that uses QtOpenGL, but I got a link error because -lGLU is not present.
cmake is used.
The only relevant line in CMakeLists.txt files seems to me `find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)`

The system is Linux 64bit, Debian unstable, qt version 4.7.3, cmake version 2.8

Answer (score 4):

GLU is neither part of OpenGL nor Qt. You must add it as an additional dependency manually; the CMake FindOpenGL module also searches for GLU

> ```
> % cmake --help-module FindOpenGL
> cmake version 2.8.1
>   FindOpenGL
>        Try to find OpenGL
>
>        Once done this will define
>
>
>          OPENGL_FOUND        - system has OpenGL
>          OPENGL_XMESA_FOUND  - system has XMESA
>          OPENGL_GLU_FOUND    - system has GLU
>          OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR  - the GL include directory
>          OPENGL_LIBRARIES    - Link these to use OpenGL and GLU
>
>
>        If you want to use just GL you can use these values
>
>          OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY   - Path to OpenGL Library
>          OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY  - Path to GLU Library
>
>
>        On OSX default to using the framework version of opengl
> ```
>
> People will
>              have to change the cache values of OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY and
>              OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY to use OpenGL with X11 on OSX
>
> ```
>        Defined in: /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindOpenGL.cmake
> ```

Answer (score 3):

I solved it this way:

```
target_link_libraries(MyProgram ${QT_LIBRARIES} GL GLU glut)
```

Comment: This is not a good CMake solution, though. Whether the GL, GLU and glut libraries are available won't be tested that way.

Answer (score 2):

If you do `set(QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE)` then `-lGLU` is included in the linker options:

```
find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)
set(QT_USE_QTOPENGL TRUE)
include(${QT_USE_FILE})
message("Libs: ${QT_LIBRARIES}")
add_executable(program main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(program ${QT_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: the following lines in CMakeLists.txt
`find_package(Qt4 REQUIRED)`
`set(QT_USE_QTXML 1)`
`set(QT_USE_QTOPENGL 1)`
`set(QT_USE_QT3SUPPORT 1)`
`include(${QT_USE_FILE})`
`message("Libs: ${QT_LIBRARIES}")`
give
`Libs: /usr/lib/libQt3Support.so;/usr/lib/libQtOpenGL.so;/usr/lib/libQtGui.so;/usr/lib/libQtXml.so;/usr/lib/libQtSql.so;/usr/lib/libQtNetwork.so;/usr/lib/libQtCore.so`

Comment: @rebli I don't think I can help any further then. The output of those lines on my system contains `-lGL` and `-lGLU`. I am also using cmake version 2.8.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the right solution, but the build completes after I added these lines to `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
find_package(OpenGL)
```

and added

```
${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
```

to

```
target_link_libraries
```